Is there a function in three.js where i can close the gaps between the blocks
function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);

    if (controls.isLocked === true) {
        const time = performance.now();
        const delta = (time - prevTime) / 1000;

        velocity.x -= velocity.x * 10.0 * delta;
        velocity.z -= velocity.z * 10.0 * delta;

        velocity.y -= 9.6 * 100.0 * delta; // gravity

        direction.z = Number(moveForward) - Number(moveBackward);
        direction.x = Number(moveRight) - Number(moveLeft);
        direction.normalize(); // this ensures consistent movements in all directions

        if (moveForward || moveBackward) velocity.z -= direction.z * 400.0 * delta;
        if (moveLeft || moveRight) velocity.x -= direction.x * 400.0 * delta;

        controls.moveRight(- velocity.x * delta);
        controls.moveForward(- velocity.z * delta);

        controls.getObject().position.y += (velocity.y * delta); // new behavior
        if (controls.getObject().position.y < 10) {
            velocity.y = 0;
            controls.getObject().position.y = 10;
            canJump = true;
        }

        prevTime = time;
    }

    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

function onMouseDown(event) {
    if (placingBlockType && controls.isLocked === true) {
        let blockGeometry, blockMaterial;

        switch (placingBlockType) {
            case "door":
                blockGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 2.5, 0.2); // Simple door dimensions
                blockMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: blockColor });
                break;
            case "window":
                blockGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 0.1); // Reduced width for the window
                blockMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: blockColor, transparent: true, opacity: 0.5 }); // Transparent window
                break;
            case "roof":
                blockGeometry = new THREE.ConeGeometry(1.5, 1, 4); // Pyramidal roof with 4 sides
                blockMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: blockColor });
                break;
            case "block":
            default:
                blockGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(2, 1, 1); // Rectangular brick shape
                blockMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: blockColor });
                break;
        }

        const raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
        const mouse = new THREE.Vector2();

        mouse.x = 0;
        mouse.y = 0;

        raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse, camera);

        const intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(objects, false);

        if (intersects.length > 0) {
            const intersect = intersects[0];

            const voxel = new THREE.Mesh(blockGeometry, blockMaterial);
            voxel.position.copy(intersect.point).add(intersect.face.normal);
            voxel.position.divideScalar(2).floor().multiplyScalar(2).addScalar(1);
            scene.add(voxel);
            objects.push(voxel);
            actionHistory.push(voxel);

            const edges = new THREE.LineSegments(new THREE.EdgesGeometry(blockGeometry), new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({ color: 0x000000 }));
            edges.position.copy(voxel.position);
            scene.add(edges);
            actionHistory.push(edges);

            // Make the new object selectable
            voxel.userData.selectable = true;
            edges.userData.selectable = true;
        }
    } else {
        selectObject(event);
    }
}

function selectObject(event) {
    const raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
    const mouse = new THREE.Vector2();

    mouse.x = (event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
    mouse.y = - (event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;

    raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse, camera);

    const intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(objects, false);

    if (intersects.length > 0) {
        const intersect = intersects[0].object;

        if (intersect.userData.selectable) {
            selectedObject = intersect;
            transformControls.attach(selectedObject);
        }
    } else {
        selectedObject = null;
        transformControls.detach();
    }
}

the above code is responsible for block placement in a 3d space

this is how the output looks like


this is how it looks when I try to place them in different direction

I have tried everything and still when I run the code there is a gap between the blocks I try to place and I'm not able to place the blocks in every direction, I can only place the blocks in one direction,cannot place it upwards or in any other direction only in one way
